# How many proof-of-work algorithm exists for crypto currencies?

Tags: proof-of-work, ethereum

How many proof-of-work algorithm exists for crypto currencies ? We know PoW in Bitcoin and Etherium are different. Is there any other algorithm used for crypto currencies ?

Answer (score 2):

Any Strong Сryptography Hash Function can be used as PoW

So, the number of algorithms can be infinite. Counting the number of currently used hash-functions has no sense.

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_work#List_of_algorithms